# Resque Web not showing all resque workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, resque

This is a bit of an odd one.`resque-1.26`. I have not made any changes to the resque environment prior to my changes.

Last week I deployed some rails changes. And when I went to the resque-web interface, i noticed that all of the workers were not showing up. Thinking that there was some dirty exit and after an exhaustive weekend debugging. I now have stand alone servers for redis, rails, and my 3 worker VMs.

I have rebuild the app server from scratch ( centos 6) , and I have rebuilt the workers.

i have tried to roll back code to an eariler state. Im confused. When I go into the worker VMs, it shows processes looking for jobs..

Im using resque-pool to manage the workers on each box, and I have even tried to manually start them. no luck. I know they are working, they are processing jobs off the queue.

How do I get the workers to register with the web-UI ?

Comment: I had this issue too I actually had to downgrade to 1.25 to get it solved.

Comment: I'm seeing this too.  It's driving me crazy!  What's more is that I can see inside the redis database that the resque entries are there... it's just that web-resque isn't seeing them.  Incredibly annoying.

Comment: I am also having this issue.  I have 9 workers and only 3 are showing now.  Also after an upgrade.